# 3D face reconstruction using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphics, 3d-reconstruction, 3d-modelling

I am doing a 3D face modeling project. I have currently developed an algorithm which maps texture from 3 input images of a face (front and 2 sides) to a base model using MATLAB.

I would like to improve my algorithm so that it will deform the generic model to a more realistic face shape depending on the individual. I'm currently looking at thin-plate splines but at a loss of how to apply this to my application.

Any help on related computer graphics methods, coding samples or links to relevant literature will be much appreciated :)

Comment: how about [this project](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/faces/)?

Comment: Thanks Shai.. Hope that It will be helpful.

Comment: Hi Shai, your suggestion is very helpful I'll post the [link](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~kemelmi/ProjectPages/Faces/paper.pdf) to the paper here in case anyone else finds it interesting